# DevExpress CircularGauge To Take Value And PerformanceCounter

Tags: c#, devexpress, performancecounter

Can I show a value a PerformanceCounter in CircularGauge ,

Code:

```
float val = performanceCounter1.NextValue();

       ((DevExpress.XtraGauges.Win.Gauges.Circular.CircularGauge)gaugeControl1.Gauges[0]).Scales[0].Value = val;
```

[image]

Comment: what is not working for you? Add a screenshot pls.

Comment: The value I am using does not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case for the CircularGauge I had to set both Value and MaxValue together:

```
((DevExpress.XtraGauges.Win.Gauges.Circular.CircularGauge)gaugeControl1.Gauges[0]).Scales[0].Value = val;

((DevExpress.XtraGauges.Win.Gauges.Circular.CircularGauge)gaugeControl1.Gauges[0]).Scales[0].MaxValue = GetGaugeMaxValue(val);

...

// helper function
private float GetGaugeMaxValue(float val)
        {
            float ret = 100;

            if (val < 100)
                ret = 100;
            else if (val < 1000)
                ret = 1000;
            else if (val < 10000)
                ret = 10000;
            else if (val < 100000)
                ret = 100000;
            else if (val < 1000000)
                ret = 1000000;

            return ret;
        }
```

see if this helps.